# Annoying issue with collisions on ThreeJS + RapierJS

Tags: objects

I'm encountering an annoying issue when importing my Blender model into Three.js (with Rapier.js physics system).

I used the Array modifier in Blender to repeat several steps for my stairs, but when I import my model into my project, the colliders do not correspond to the shape of each step.

Instead, they encompass the entire object.

Here is a screenshot of the issue I'm currently experiencing :

[image: Collision issue]

How can I achieve a good collision system on Blender ? Because If I make my stairs step by step, it work but this is so annoying to process like that.. especially for very repetitive objects...

Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about using Blender, but did you try applying the array modifier before exporting?

Comment: Hello John,

Thanks for your reply.
Yes, I applied the array modifier but I still have the same issue..

Comment: Anyone (including me) who doesn't use threeJS won't have a clue what a 'collider' is (or Rapier.JS for that matter)!

Comment: Can I just subdivise the steps of my array to get X similars objects in my hierarchy ?

Comment: If I create my stairs cube by cube, individual collisions work : 

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2024/11/5/1710506860-individual.png

But if I use array, the whole object is impacted by a global collision even outside the bounds of my steps..

Comment: You should be able to apply the modifier, go into Edit mode, then hit P > Separate by Loose Parts. Each step should then be a separate object when you go back into Object mode.

Comment: Bro, you are my day hero, IT PERFECTLY WORKS like that, thanks 1000X John Eason :-)

Comment: No problem. I'll add it as an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Create the steps from a cube using the <kbd>Array</kbd> modifier.

[image]

Apply the modifier by hovering over it and hitting <kbd>CTRL-A</kbd>. Then go into <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode, select <kbd>A</kbd>ll and hit <kbd>P</kbd> > Separate > <kbd>By Loose Parts</kbd>.

[image]

Back in <kbd>Object</kbd> mode, you'll see that each step is now a separate object:

[image]